# Guice How to inject dependencies to an object instantiated from a dynamically loaded class

Tags: java, guice, dynamic-class-loaders

I want to load a plugin which is dependent to some features of my application. 
I can create an instance of the entry class. Bu I cannot inject required dependencies to it.

For example lets assume that I have class in the plugin like that:

```
class ThirdPartyService implements Service {
  //no argument constructor and overridden methods

  //Inject database config which is known by application to the service:
  @Inject
  void setDatabaseConfig(DatabaseConfig dbConfig) {
    this.dbConfig = dbConfig;
  }
}
```

The guice modules in the application don't know `ThirdParyService`. Because it is a dynamically loaded class. So I cannot bind `Service` to this class. Is there any way to inject `DatabaseConfig` to a `ThirdParyService` instance?

Note: I don't want to load the plugins at the beginning  of the application. Instead, I want to load plugins at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Use injector.injectMembers()

This will call the setter injection